# How to indent the first line in each paragraph in Quarto docx output?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I am currently writing a report that I will export to a docx file. I would like to have an indentation at the beginning of each paragraph but I couldn't find how to do so in Quarto in Rstudio.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Word documents specifically, create a reference document with the Quarto console command

```
quarto pandoc -o custom-reference-doc.docx \
   --print-default-data-file reference.docx
```

Set up the indentation style within Word for your reference .docx file. Use that file for styling your Quarto doc with YAML

```
format:
  docx:
    reference-doc: custom-reference-doc.docx
```

More info here https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/ms-word-templates.html